# As a french tax resident, do I have to pay french capital gains tax on a UK property

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gain, capital-gains-tax, france

I have had a UK property for 11 years (currently let out)

I live in France and have been tax resident here for 6 years.

If I sold the property today, would any Tax be due anywhere?

Comment: At the very least, I'd expect you'd need to pay it in France (your country of tax residency). Is there some reason why you think you might not have to?

Comment: because I've not seen anything that says I should. CGT on property is usually payable in the country the property is in. Closest answer I have is that it *should* be paid in France, but their system is only set up for French properties..

Answer (score 3):

This 2013 [article](http://www.kentingtons.com/blog/tax-planning/capital-gains-tax/) claims (my bold)

> There is currently much confusion since the UK / France tax treaty
>   changed and one point of confusion is how property is taxed for
>   capital gains. ... Since the change in the UK / France tax treaty,
>   **capital gains from UK property, for French residents, are now taxed in
>   France under French rules**.

However, details may have changed again as UK HMRC info [here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/capital-gains-tax-for-non-residents-uk-residential-property) (and [here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/capital-gains-tax-for-non-residents-calculating-taxable-gain-or-loss) maybe also relevant) mentions "...after 5 April 2015..." and may impact the French/UK tax takes under tax treaty's double taxation avoidance principles.

Looks messy.  I'd want professional advice.